# visual studio code reads my css file as post css file

Tags: visual-studio-code

i don't know what happened, but when i open my visual studio code apparently all my css file icons becomes post css. i can't get the autocomplete working when i edit the css file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall any extensions, thats happened to me a few times

Comment: @PyMan which extensions did you uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: I had HTML and CSS Support, I also think you should reinstall VS code if anything

Comment: Check your icon-theme extension. It might be overriding or not showing correct icon.

Comment: Open VS code , press ``Shift + Ctrl + p`` and search for  **``Disable all installed extensions ``** , **``reopen VScode and test again``** , To know where extension that make this enable extension one by one